# RoR - Conditionally redirect to addressed based on domain extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We're serving the same RoR site to two domains; oursite.co.uk and oursite.ie.

Each domain has a subdomain; subdom.oursite.co.uk and subdomain.oursite.ie

We want to redirect from the main site to the correct subdomain, so that the domain extension remains the same.

I'm not an RoR developer, so I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct for conditionally assigning a string to a variable, and I'm also not sure if `request.original_url` will work in routes.rb.

I've tried variations around this theme so far:

```
link = String.new()
link = (request.original_url == "ourdomain.ie" ? "subdom.ourdomain.ie" : "subdom.ourdomain.co.uk")
```

How can I get the current domain extension and then conditionally assign the string value?

Comment: `request` will not work in `routes.rb`. Think of `routes.rb` as how your app figures out its routing table once, at startup. Think of `request` as [an instance of the Rack::Request class](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request) that is only available within the context of an HTTP transaction.

Comment: You don't need `String.new` in Ruby. Just `link = "subdom.#{request.original_url}"` (using [String interpolation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation))

Comment: @anothermh - Ah ok, that makes sense. So is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?